# what certificate use to digitally sign PS script

Tags: powershell, certificate, sign

I followed articles describing how to digitally sign PowerShell scripts by creating self-signed certificate, importing it into trusted root certification authorities, then sign the script with:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName cert_name -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\ -Type Codesigning
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath D:\script.ps1 -Certificate (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\ -CodeSigningCert)
```

this works for me, however I'd like to use the certificate pushed from AD and is trusted throughout whole domain. If use try to use one, which has too "Code Signing" purpose, this is output from same command:

```
SignerCertificate     Status       Path
-----------------     ------       ----
                      UnknownError script.ps1
```

Why is SignerCertificate field empty, and why script doesn't get signed ? Can anybody explain what am I missing here ?

Comment: Does the certificate have a private key?

Comment: No I don't have private key for this cert. When I was testing this functionality with self certificate I created myself (self-signed) and imported it into trusted root certification authorities directory, I unchecked import private key. Also when I compared those 2 certificates I could not see any difference it could cause problem. Is private key needed ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-documented use case. For example:

> Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Sign Windows PowerShell Scripts with an
> Enterprise Windows PKI? Part 1 and 2
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-2-of-2

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path 'cert:\currentuser\my\ -CodeSigningCert'
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath 'D:\Scripts\\demoscript.ps1' -Certificate $cert -TimestampServer 'http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode'
```